# N level hierarchy Array Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm writting a questionnaires application, there are questions with responses, those responses can have child questions, these questions might have responses with another child questions then being a N level hierarchy, I need to find the best strategy to load this in a html  list, using the normal ng-repeat I have a limit of level, in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/olmanx21/h87szshj/) I chain 4 levels, but it could be more than that, I appreciate any comment or suggestion.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl',function ($scope){
$scope.questionnaire = [
    {
        QuestionID: 1,
        Description: "Question 1",
        Responses: [{
            RespDescription: "Response 1"
        },
        {
            RespDescription: "Response 2",
            ChildQuestions: [{
                QuestionID: 2,
                Description: "Child Question 2.1",
                Responses: [{
                    RespDescription: "Child Response 2.1.1"
                },
                {
                    RespDescription: "Child Response 2.1.2",
                    ChildQuestions: [{
                        QuestionID: 3,
                        Description: "Child Question 2.1.2.1",
                        Responses:[{
                            RespDescription: "Child Response...",
                            ChildQuestions:[{
                                QuestionID:4,
                                Description: "Other Child Question",
                                Responses:[{
                                    RespDescription: "Response..."
                                }]

                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
];
```

})

Comment: There are multiple directives out there created to handle this kind of structure;  one such is https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar questionnaire type app with a structure like that. What I did was to do is create a back-end api that has a tree-like structure of relations.

You want this to be hooked into a back end and not just written out, because otherwise it could get incredibly messy, a lot like a callback hell.

[Here](https://github.com/hellsan631/questionair) is the starting of the project on github. It uses loopback to do the data-modeling and hooks into an angular front-end, but you can use a back-end any way you like.

The [idea](https://github.com/hellsan631/questionair/blob/master/server/boot/01-dummy.js) is that when you query a first [question](https://github.com/hellsan631/questionair/blob/master/server/models/question.json), it has a few child [answers](https://github.com/hellsan631/questionair/blob/master/server/models/answer.json). Each of those answers then has another question attached to it, and so on, and so on. The relationships of each model are whats important here.

This way you can create a controller that when you select a answerC to questionA, it would query the database for the related questionC object, and include all answers linked that that new questionC.

You would then add the newly loaded questionC with its answers to the main array of questions and scroll down (or something like that).

A quick sudo code example:

```
//controller.js
app.controller('questionair', function(Answer, Question){
  //Lets load our first question, with the related 3 answers
  Question.findById({id: 1}, {include: 'answers'}).$promise
    .then(function(question){
      $scope.questions = [question];
    });

  //function that gets new question from our select answer
  $scope.answerMe = function(questionId){
    Question.findById({id: questionId}, {include: 'answers'}).$promise
      .then(function(newQuestion){
        $scope.questions.push(newQuestion);
      },function(error){
        console.log('You\'ve answered the last question!');
      });
  };
});

//index.html
<div ng-repeat="question in questions">
   <h2>{{ question.text }}</h2>
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="answer in question.answers" 
         ng-click="answerMe(answer.questionId)">
       {{ answer.text }}
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes actually I'm using all the data from a Backend, with the same structure that you have in your project, for example purposes I used a hardcoded array :), I checked your solution,and if I'm not wrong I noticed that you queue the child questions together with the first level questions, when in answerMe function you add the loaded child question to a $scope.questions array ng-repeat is going to queue after the last main question and not under its parent asnwer

Comment: The array is meant to be the basis for displaying the questions in order. If you'd prefer to store it in a tree structure then you can of course, but having ng-repeat go through a tree would be very hard.

Comment: Its just much easier for you management to store it internally to match the display in that example. When your user answers a question you can also make a tree to model the question path they choose, then just throw that tree into a nosql data store like mongo.

Answer (score 0):

I was through Mark Lagendijk's [code in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JAIyolmqPqO9KsynSiZp?p=preview) and He had the solution for this task, recursivity is the secret,with a directive calling itself is possible to represent a N levels estructure, The key is the service called **RecursionHelper** that compile and avoid the infinite loop in the directive, I adapted the code to my necessity and this is the result:

RecursionHelper

```
/* 
 * An Angular service which helps with creating recursive directives.
* @author Mark Lagendijk
* @license MIT
*/
angular.module('RecursionHelper', []).factory('RecursionHelper', ['$compile', function($compile){
return {
    /**
     * Manually compiles the element, fixing the recursion loop.
     * @param element
     * @param [link] A post-link function, or an object with function(s) registered via pre and post properties.
     * @returns An object containing the linking functions.
     */
    compile: function(element, link){
        // Normalize the link parameter
        if(angular.isFunction(link)){
            link = { post: link };
        }

        // Break the recursion loop by removing the contents
        var contents = element.contents().remove();
        var compiledContents;
        return {
            pre: (link && link.pre) ? link.pre : null,
            /**
             * Compiles and re-adds the contents
             */
            post: function(scope, element){
                // Compile the contents
                if(!compiledContents){
                    compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                }
                // Re-add the compiled contents to the element
                compiledContents(scope, function(clone){
                    element.append(clone);
                });

                // Call the post-linking function, if any
                if(link && link.post){
                    link.post.apply(null, arguments);
                }
            }
        };
    }
};
}]);
```

questionTree Directive :

```
directives.directive('questionTree', function (RecursionHelper) {
return {
    restrict: "AE",
    scope: {
        items: "=",
    },
    priority: 500,
    replace: true,
    //I use templateURL but for simplicity I used inline template in this code
    template: function (el, attr) {
        var itemType = attr["itemType"];

        if (itemType == "question") {
            return '<ul>'+
                     '<li ng-repeat="item in items">'+
                         '<div ng- click="loadChildResponses(item);$event.stopPropagation();">{{item.Description}}</div>'+
    '<question-tree items="item.Responses" item-type="reponse"></question-tree>'+
                     '</li>'+
                   '</ul>';

        }
        else {
            return '<ul>'+
                       '<li ng-repeat="item in items">'+
                           '<div ng-click="loadChildQuestions(item);$event.stopPropagation();">{{item.Description}}</div>'+
                           '<question-tree items="item.ModelWizardQuestions" item-type="question"></question-tree>'+
                        '</li>'+
                      '</ul>';

        }

    },
    controller: function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.loadChildResponses = function (item) {



            $http.get(siteUrls.GetReponses + "?QuestionID=" + item.QuestionID)
           .success(function (data) {
               if (data && data.length > 0) {
                   item.Responses = data;
               }
           });
        };

        $scope.loadChildQuestions = function (item) {



            $http.get(siteUrls.getChildQuestions + "?ResponseID=" + item.ResponseID)
           .success(function (data) {
               if (data && data.length > 0) {
                   item.Questions = data;
               }
           });
        };
    },
    compile: function (element) {
        // Use the compile function from the RecursionHelper,
        // And return the linking function(s) which it returns
        return RecursionHelper.compile(element);
    }
}
});
```

So, I load the first level of the questions, and attach the questionTree directive, and the application is able to load N levels.

The HTML:

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="question in Questions">{{question.Description}}
      <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="response in question.Responses"><span>{{response.Description}}</span>
           <question-tree items="response.Questions" item-type="question"></question-tree>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```